# Configure nginx as a bridge between two apps

Tags: nginx

I have two apps being runned on separate Tomcat's, on 80 and 8080 port respectively. URL's in these apps the same, only differs with mentioned ports. I need to send HTTP-request from 1 to 2 but don't have to change code, so I tried to configure nginx with smth like:

```
server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name blabla.net;
          location / {
              proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
              proxy_pass         http://blabla.net:80;
          }
    }
```

but trying to start nginx have:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

Is there any way to solve it, I mean run nginx on separate port to make a bridge between two apps? Thank you!

Comment: You have one Tomcat running on port 8080 and you are trying to `bind` your nginx to `same port`. This won't work.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Could you suggest some workaround for my case? I'm actually developer and have poor knowledge of nginx

Comment: There is no workaround, you need proper architecture/design.